# What type of being is the Hulk classified as?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

After reading the Hulk's entry at [Marvel.com](http://marvel.com/universe/Hulk_(Bruce_Banner)) I'm still unsure what exactly Bruce's alternate form is technically classified as. The only description given about the Hulk is "monster", but it's used in different ways:

### [Multiple Personality Disorder](http://marvel.com/universe/Hulk_(Bruce_Banner)#Multiple_Personality_Disorder) (literal)

> Gamma-powered psychiatrist Leonard "Doc" Samson captured the Hulk and successfully separated Banner and his alter ego. Without Banner's psyche to restrain him, the Hulk became a greater danger than ever before. Realizing there was only one way to reign in the Hulk, Banner agreed to merge with **the monster**.

### [World War Hulks](http://marvel.com/universe/Hulk_(Bruce_Banner)#World_War_Hulks) (figurative)

> During the brawl Skaar accidentally placed several innocents at risk. Hulk saved their lives, **proving he wasn't the monster Skaar or Banner made him out to be**. Father and son finally reconciled and decided to act as a family.

So it seems like the term "monster" isn't really how people in-the-know would consider the Hulk.

**So what is he?** Is the Hulk a mutation? A limited evolution? An involuntary super power? Is he still considered human? If there are multiple, conflicting possibilities, then the most recent one will do.

Comment: An anthropomorphic personificationof anger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hulk is a [human mutate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutate_(comics)).

> In the Marvel Comics universe, the term **mutate** refers to humans who were mutated into superhumans, as opposed to mutants, inhumans, and other sub-races of humanity whose superhuman characteristics are genetically inherited.

Hulk, Spider-Man, Daredevil, and the Fantastic Four are all examples of human mutates.

He is generally seen as a Dr. Jekyll / Mr. Hyde monser, but his exact personality and abilities depend on which story you're currently reading.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(comics)#Powers_and_abilities):

> Following his accidental exposure to gamma rays during the detonation of an experimental bomb, Banner is physically transformed into the Hulk when subjected to emotional stress, at or against his will, often leading to destructive rampages and conflicts that complicate Banner's civilian life. The Hulk's level of strength is normally conveyed as proportionate to his level of anger. Commonly portrayed as a raging savage, the Hulk has been represented with other personalities based on Banner's fractured psyche, from a mindless, destructive force, to a brilliant warrior, or genius scientist in his own right.